# How to make Jquery Select2 work with ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-select2

I've been struggling lately with Jquery Select2 ([Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)), trying to achieve ajax callbacks that get data from a ASP MVC ActionResult.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="e2" style="width: 500px;">
```

And this is the js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#e2").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax:{
          url: "http://localhost:1800/Test/GetCountries",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            data: function(term, page){
                return {
                    query: term
                };
            },
            results: function(data){
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        }
    });

});
```

GetCountries function is very straightforward, it just returns the countries that matches the term of search. This is a sample when searching for the term "united":

```
[{"id":"AE","text":"United Arab Emirates"},{"id":"UK","text":"United Kingdom"},{"id":"US","text":"United States"}]
```

I have tried changing the format from application/json to text back and forth with no success. I think I am missing something on the json my function is returning, but after three hours I still have no clue what could be wrong here.

When I look into the Chrome debugger on the network tab, it seems to call the function and data is being sent. However when I type letters nothing displays, it just shows the "searching..." text forever.

If someone out there has been into the same situation, please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked for this one. I haven't find the time to make the Select2 work, although a workaround on default Bootstrap's Typeahead can do.

So, if someone comes around, don't bother answering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is

```
dataType:"jsonp"
```

Solution:

```
 dataType:"json"
```

See more [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the issue actually. I need cross-domain calls on production. What I ended up with, was creating a JS autocomplete control. Took me 4 days and works great.